# is it possible to remove "Google Frontend" from google app engine response header?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, httpresponse, response-headers

I would like to know if there is any way to remove the server name(Google Frontend) from the google app engine response header to hide that the app is deployed on GAE.

Comment: Why do you want to hide this fact?

Comment: @unforgettableid Why not?

Comment: I am also Looking For same As Per Google Documents we can remove Server header. Check this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-requests-are-handled#headers_removed  But Not Getting How to remove Server header.

Comment: GAE java documentation link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled#headers_removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. DNS also gives you away.

Comment: Check this Link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled#headers_removed

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite any headers? I have an error is the Content Security Policy header.. :(

Answer (score 9):

Consider a reverse proxy in front of your GAE app. The DNS will be to your reverse proxy server.

You can mess with the response headers on the way back out.

This starts to break down the killer advantage of GAE - that it "easily scales on googles infrastructure" - but a single nginx server for example will cope with huge traffic.

Once you have outgrown your single reverse proxy - you will probably be attracting money and attention, and no longer be the one worrying about the proxy.